# can't build it: error: class, interface, or enum expected

Tags: java, class, enums, interface

I really can't find the root of problem,
I was able to build it previous, and didn't make any change at all.

Those are the two errors i am having:
error: illegal start of type
error: class, interface, or enum expected

I wasn't able to provide all the code, but i checked all the code at least 50 times and wasn't really able to find where the issue is.

```
public static final Creator<FlickrPhoto> CREATOR = new Creator<FlickrPhoto>() {
    @Override
    public FlickrPhoto createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new FlickrPhoto(in);
    }

    @Override
    public FlickrPhoto[] newArray(int size) {
        return new FlickrPhoto[size];
    }
};

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeLong(id);
    dest.writeString(owner);
    dest.writeString(secret);
    dest.writeString(server);
    dest.writeString(farm);
    dest.writeString(title);
    dest.writeByte((byte) (isPublic ? 1 : 0));
    dest.writeString(ownerName);
    dest.writeString(dateAdded);
    dest.writeInt(license);
    dest.writeString(description);
    dest.writeString(dateTaken);
    dest.writeString(views);
    dest.writeString(tags);
    dest.writeString(placeId);
    dest.writeString(media);
    dest.writeString(thumb);
    dest.writeString(size_n);
    dest.writeString(url_n);
    dest.writeString(size_z);
    dest.writeString(url_z);
    dest.writeString(size_c);
    dest.writeString(url_c);
    dest.writeString(size_l);
    dest.writeString(url_l);
    dest.writeString(size_h);
    dest.writeString(url_h);
    dest.writeString(size_k);
    dest.writeString(url_k);
    dest.writeString(size_o);
    dest.writeString(url_o);
}


public static List<FlickrPhoto> jsonToPhotoList(String jsonString) throws JSONException {
    List<FlickrPhoto> list = new ArrayList<>();


    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    JSONObject jPhotos = json.getJSONObject("photos");

    TempData.getInstance().page = JsonUtils.getInt(jPhotos, "page");
    TempData.getInstance().pages = JsonUtils.getInt(jPhotos, "pages");
    TempData.getInstance().perPage = JsonUtils.getInt(jPhotos, "perpage");
    int total = JsonUtils.getInt(jPhotos, "total");
    TempData.getInstance().total = total;
    if (total > 0) {
        JSONArray photoArray = jPhotos.getJSONArray("photo");
        list.addAll(parsePhotoJson(photoArray.toString()));
    }
    return list;
}

public static List<FlickrPhoto> parsePhotoJson(String jsonString) throws JSONException {
    List<FlickrPhoto> list = new ArrayList<>();

    JSONArray photoArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);

    for (int i = 0; i < photoArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject j = photoArray.getJSONObject(i);

        FlickrPhoto photo = new FlickrPhoto();
        photo.id = JsonUtils.getLong(j, "id");
        photo.owner = JsonUtils.getString(j, "owner");
        photo.secret = JsonUtils.getString(j, "secret");
        photo.server = JsonUtils.getString(j, "server");
        photo.farm = JsonUtils.getString(j, "farm");
        photo.title = JsonUtils.getString(j, "title");
        photo.isPublic = JsonUtils.getBoolean(j, "ispublic");
        photo.ownerName = JsonUtils.getString(j, "ownername");

            /*long dateAdded = JsonUtils.getLong(j, "dateadded");
            photo.dateAdded = getDateFromUnix(dateAdded); */

        photo.license = JsonUtils.getInt(j, "license");

            /* JSONObject description = j.getJSONObject("description");
            photo.description = JsonUtils.getString(description, "_content"); */

            /* String datetaken = JsonUtils.getString(j, "datetaken");
            photo.dateTaken = getDateFromString(datetaken); */

        //photo.views = JsonUtils.getString(j, "views");
        photo.tags = JsonUtils.getString(j, "tags");
        //photo.placeId = JsonUtils.getString(j, "place_id");
        photo.media = JsonUtils.getString(j, "media");
        photo.thumb = JsonUtils.getString(j, "url_n");

        photo.url_n = JsonUtils.getString(j, "url_n");

        if (j.has("width_n") && j.has("height_n"))
            photo.size_n = JsonUtils.getString(j, "width_n") + " * " + JsonUtils.getString(j, "height_n");

        photo.url_z = JsonUtils.getString(j, "url_z");

        if (j.has("width_z") && j.has("height_z"))
            photo.size_z = JsonUtils.getString(j, "width_z") + " * " + JsonUtils.getString(j, "height_z");

        photo.url_c = JsonUtils.getString(j, "url_c");

        if (j.has("width_c") && j.has("height_c"))
            photo.size_c = JsonUtils.getString(j, "width_c") + " * " + JsonUtils.getString(j, "height_c");

        photo.url_l = JsonUtils.getString(j, "url_l");

        if (j.has("width_l") && j.has("height_l"))
            photo.size_l = JsonUtils.getString(j, "width_l") + " * " + JsonUtils.getString(j, "height_l");

        photo.url_h = JsonUtils.getString(j, "url_h");

        if (j.has("width_h") && j.has("height_h"))
            photo.size_h = JsonUtils.getString(j, "width_h") + " * " + JsonUtils.getString(j, "height_h");



        if (j.has("width_k") && j.has("height_k"))
            photo.size_k = JsonUtils.getString(j, "width_k") + " * " + JsonUtils.getString(j, "height_k");

        photo.url_o = JsonUtils.getString(j, "url_o");

        if (j.has("width_o") && j.has("height_o"))
            photo.size_o = JsonUtils.getString(j, "width_o") + " * " + JsonUtils.getString(j, "height_o");


        }


    }


    return list;
}
```

The error appears to be at the last lines

```
}


    return list;
}
```

}

Comment: This is a simple typographical error. Format your code and you'll see quickly enough.

Answer (score 0):

There is no opening `{` on this line:

```
 if (j.has("width_o") && j.has("height_o"))
```

yet, it seems you are expecting one down here:

```
            photo.size_o = JsonUtils.getString(j, "width_o") + " * " + JsonUtils.getString(j, "height_o");


        }
```

This will cause a brace mis-match, which can cause all kinds of errors that point you in the wrong direction.

Thus, what you want to do is add one to this line, like this:

```
 if (j.has("width_o") && j.has("height_o")) {
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply,
I did tried your recommendation but received more errors.
Could you please include your solution inside the code.

Comment: We'll adding the opening "if (j.has("width_o") && j.has("height_o"))" here did caused many other problems.

Comment: You moved the line? That's not what I meant. I'll clarify my answer.

Comment: @LuxusMind  Updated.

Comment: Glad I could help. That's definitely the answer then?

Comment: Yes that is. Thank you. I also tried formatting the code before but that wasn't the issue.